# Compilation failed in Java for "android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY"

Tags: java, android, permissions, network-traffic

I am facing 1 issue and could not solve it yet.

```
ERROR : "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.SecurityException: NetworkStats: Neither user 10053 nor current process has android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY".
```

I am implementing this in API 23 which is having a runtime security implementation for permission, I hope you understand what I am trying to say. I was able to add android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY in Manifest but I am not able to add the same permission in Java file because its giving the compilation error. Could you please help ?

Below is the Manifest.xml code :- (Working fine with a waring)

[image]

Below is the Java code :- (Compilation Failed)

[image]

Comment: I strongly recommend you using Android Studio, its better than eclipse because the Android plug-in for eclipse is deprecated. Maybe Android Studio could suggest you a better approach

Comment: @Jaco Agree with you

Answer (score 0):

It allows only for System Apps not for Normal Applications. So we can't get the access for read Network Usage History.

you want access network information you should use this permission

```
"android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

Allows applications to access information about networks.

and refer this url : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html

Comment: we can't use the same permissions, because they support only for System applications.  And no required run time permission for network usage access.